# how to merge 2 database results in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 columns as follow:

```
A  |  B
---|---
7  |  1
7  |  2
3  |  7
4  |  5
-------
```

**I want to get 1 column containing (1,2,3).**

Currently i'm quering this:

```
SELECT  `A` ,  `B` 
FROM  `mytable` 
WHERE  `A` =7
OR  `B` =7
```

but I'm getting 2 columns containing the number 7 in both sides A and B.

*i'm sure there is a way to get what I want but I don't know how to google that!!*

Comment: what output you are expecting?

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
SELECT
  case when A=7 then B else A end
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE
  7 IN (A, B)
```

If you want a single column, you could use this:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(case when A=7 then B else A end
               ORDER BY case when A=7 then B else A end)
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE 7 IN (A, B)
```

See fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a705d/5).

If value of both A and B could be 7 at the same time, and you want to skip that row, you could substitute:

```
WHERE 7 IN (A, B)
```

with

```
WHERE A=7 XOR B=7
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what you need, but I'm guessing something like this:

```
SELECT A FROM mytable WHERE B=7
UNION
SELECT B FROM mytable WHERE A=7
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you looking for this

```
   SELECT myresult from (

          SELECT A myresult FROM Table1 WHERE A IN (1,2,3)
          UNION
          SELECT B myresult FROM Table1 WHERE B IN (1,2,3)
                   )t
   ORDER BY myresult
```

this will out put :

```
 MYRESULT
   1
   2
   3
```

[**SQL DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e29f/9)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT A as Single FROM mytable WHERE B=7   UNION   
SELECT B  as Single FROM mytable WHERE A=7 ORDER BY Single;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting result as 1, 2, 3 use below.

```
SELECT colB as NewCol FROM tableName WHERE colA=7
UNION
SELECT colA as NewCol FROM tableName WHERE colB=7;
```

If you want both columns simply use

```
SELECT colA, colB FROM tableName WHERE colA=7 OR colB=7;
```

### [Demo at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0209/8)

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I want, 
I didn't knew there's UNION on MySQL :P

Answer (score 0):

you have to try this code..

```
SELECT b as value FROM users WHERE a='7'
UNION All
SELECT a as value FROM users WHERE b='7'
```

this query must help you.